# AlarmManager not sending alarms on the correct time

Tags: java, android

I am using AlarmManager to send a notification at a specified time.

Here is my code for the BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class NotificationReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS = 1;
    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 0;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i("NotificationReceiver", "Sending notification");

        // Check and request permissions if needed
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.VIBRATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED ||
                ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(context, Manifest.permission.WAKE_LOCK) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // Request permissions dynamically if not granted
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions((Activity) context,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.VIBRATE, Manifest.permission.WAKE_LOCK},
                    REQUEST_CODE_PERMISSIONS);

            return;
        }

        createNotificationChannel(context);

        Intent notificationActivity = new Intent(context, NotificationActivity.class);
        notificationActivity.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, notificationActivity, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "ProjectNotification")
                .setContentTitle("Hi")
                .setContentText("Hello there")
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notifications)
                .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_MAX)
                .setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManagerCompat notificationManagerCompat = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context);
        notificationManagerCompat.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, builder.build());
    }

    private void createNotificationChannel(Context context) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel("ProjectNotification",
                    "Project Notifications", NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH);
            channel.setDescription("Channel for project notifications");
            channel.enableLights(true);
            channel.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
            channel.enableVibration(true);

            NotificationManager notificationManager = context.getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my code for creating a notification:

```
private void setNotification(long timeInMillis) {
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, NotificationReceiver.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE);

        try{
            alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeInMillis, pendingIntent);
        }
        catch (SecurityException e){
            Log.e("setNotification", e.toString());
            try{
                alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeInMillis, pendingIntent);
            }
            catch (SecurityException ex){
                Log.e("setNotification", ex.toString());
                alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, timeInMillis, pendingIntent);
            }
        }
}
```

Here is the code for the time picker:

```
private void onClickTimeDialog(View view) {

        EditText editText = (EditText) view;

        Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();

        int hour = calendar1.get(Calendar.HOUR);
        int minute = calendar1.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        // Creating the grey background.
        View transparentGreyView = new View(context);
        transparentGreyView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#80808080"));
        ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(
                ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT
        );
        transparentGreyView.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
        transparentGreyView.setTag("greyBackground");
        popConstLayout.addView(transparentGreyView);


        TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(context,
                new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view12, int hourOfDay, int minute12) {
                        if (hourOfDay != 12) {
                            String timeShort = hourOfDay + ":" + minute12 + " AM";
                            @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa");
                            try {
                                editText.setHint(sdf.format(Objects.requireNonNull(sdf.parse(timeShort))));
                            } catch (ParseException e) {
                                throw new RuntimeException(e);
                            }
                        } else {
                            String timeShort = hourOfDay + ":" + minute12 + " PM";
                            @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat") SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa");
                            try {
                                editText.setHint(sdf.format(Objects.requireNonNull(sdf.parse(timeShort))));
                            } catch (ParseException e) {
                                throw new RuntimeException(e);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }, hour, minute, false);
        timePickerDialog.setOnDismissListener(new DialogInterface.OnDismissListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialogInterface) {
                // Removing the grey background on dismiss.
                View removeView = popConstLayout.findViewWithTag("greyBackground");

                if (removeView != null) {
                    popConstLayout.removeView(removeView);
                }
            }
        });
        timePickerDialog.show();

    }
```

Here is the code for getting the time from the time picker:

```
String time = "04:00 PM"; //example;
int hour = Integer.parseInt(time.split(":")[0]);
int minute = Integer.parseInt(time.split(":")[1].split(" ")[0]);
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
setNotification(calendar.getTimeInMillis());
```

When doing:

```
Log.e("test", String.valueOf(timeInMillis));
```

in the **setNotification** method, for the time **10:44 AM, 22/03/2024**, the return time in millis is **1711104240000**.

[image]

The time in millis is exactly what it should be but still, the alarm goes off just a second later (or a few seconds later) as shown here:

[image]

Does anyone know what is the problem? I really don't know.
I tried printing out the timeInMillis to check if it got an incorrect time. No the time in millis gave the exact time of the alarm, but still the notification went out a few seconds after setting it.

I have all of these permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

Comment: Are you sure that timestamp converter right? AlarmManager can fire immediately when timestamp is past time

Comment: How can I check what the timestamp is and change it accordingly? The timeInMillis is correct though.

Comment: I mean the millis value. Add the code that convert input data from date and time pickers to mills and example of the value.

Comment: I added all of the code you asked and an example.

Comment: As I understand `hourOfDay` in `onTimeSet` is always 24-hours. So are you sure about that only 12 value need to check `hourOfDay != 12` when create string with am/pm? And where is am/pm when parse value to calendar?

Comment: Yeah my bad. I don't need that if and else. Either way, the time itself comes out fine. If I do for example 16:00, the simpleDateFormat will convert it to 04:00 PM.

Comment: Nevermind. You are absolutely correct. I didn't convert back to 24 hour format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the insights from [Viewed](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5894542/viewed), I realized that my mistake is converting the time to 12h format but not converting it back to 24h format.

The problem with my code is that the time of the alarm is before the current time, so the notification is sent.

What I needed to add to the code for it to work:

```
String time = "04:00 PM" //example
Date date = null;
SimpleDateFormat inputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm aa");
SimpleDateFormat outputFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
try {
    date = inputFormat.parse(time);
} catch (ParseException e) {
    throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
time = outputFormat.format(Objects.requireNonNull(date));
```

I also added this in order to make sure that the time is after:

```
long currentTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);

Log.e("WARN", calendar.getTime().toString());

long setTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
Timestamp setTimestamp = new Timestamp(setTime);
Timestamp currentTimestamp = new Timestamp(currentTime);

if (setTimestamp.after(currentTimestamp))
{
     setNotification(calendar.getTimeInMillis(), "day");
} else {
     Log.e("createNotifications", "Notification time is before current time.");
}
```